# HighCharts (Stock) Styling Issues (Mobile and Date Selector)

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here's a HighStock chart with buttons and date selector: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/styling/)

Two questions:

1.) Is it possible to add a border radius to the date selector input fields? 
    I see options like `inputBoxBorderColor` as well as `inputStyle`, but nothing
    seems to work out of the box. Any ideas?

2.) If you make your browser smaller (while viewing the chart), you'll notice the datepicker 
    and range selector buttons overlap on each other. What are some options for fixing this?
    I don't want to force a width, as I'm looking for responsive design.
    How difficult is it to create an external datepicker and are there any examples out there?
    Plus one for JSFiddle examples :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Unforutnately it is not available, but you can post your idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com).

2) You can only disable inputs, by width

```
inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working? See here: http://jsfiddle.net/r9C84/ EDIT: Ah, the min-width of 600px was preventing the trigger. However, it only appears to apply on initialization, and not dynamically. Going to try changing the attribute outside the chart initialization.

Comment: No luck on the above yet. Any insight on how I can dynamically toggle inputEnabled based on view size? JQuery's window resize isn't working as expected.

Comment: But this inputs should disappear dynamically, when you resize?

Comment: I know, but you can only use inputEnabled option, nothing more.

Comment: Ah, okay. Your #2 solution suffices for now; I will considered this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #2, if you wanted to hide the date range selector for smaller screens / window widths and have this work dynamically, you could use a media query (I used a sample breakpoint below):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .highcharts-input-group {
    display:  none;
  }
}
```